# Exclude rows from query if their count is less than x

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called "cities" that looks like this:

| ID | city |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | paris |
| 2 | paris |
| 3 | london |
| 4 | london |
| 5 | london |
| 6 | london |

I want to exclude from a larger query all rows where the count of a unique city's appearance is less than 3.  So in the case of the table above, excluding the Paris rows.

I'm expecting something like this.

| ID | city |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | london |
| 4 | london |
| 5 | london |
| 6 | london |

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNT window function to get the desired result -

```
SELECT ID, city
  FROM (SELECT ID, city, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY city) CNT
          FROM YOUR_TABLE
       )
 WHERE CNT >= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this query, the subquery calculates the count of each city and filters only those with a count greater than or equal to 3.

```
SELECT c.ID, c.city
FROM cities c
JOIN (
  SELECT city
  FROM cities
  GROUP BY city
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) sub ON c.city = sub.city;
```